# Is letter spacing supported in Spark Label?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I can't seem to adjust the letter and character spacing in the Spark Label. I've tried setting the tracking left and right and the letter spacing. Is it supported?

Answer (score 4):

Use `trackingLeft` (The amount of tracking (manual kerning) to be applied to the left of each character) or `trackingRight`  (The amount of tracking (manual kerning) to be applied to the right of each character).
For the Spark theme, `letterSpacing` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

use css(style) for that

```
.lbl
{
    letterSpacing: 1;
}
```

Comment: `For the Spark theme, this is not supported. See trackingLeft and trackingRight.`  From the [ASDocs](https://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/Label.html)